# SSAS Cube -Process Time

Tags: ssas, cube

I need to capture historical data around the time it takes to process SSAS Cubes in a Tabular Model environment. The scheduling is done via Autosys and SQL Server Agenst .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to export the SQL Server agent log to CSV and then analyze the data in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use SSIS Project Deployment that has built in reporting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213358.aspx). Then historical data will be captured automatically & queried using views (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878135.aspx).

You could also download SSRS reports for SSISDB for more detailed reporting from https://ssisreportingpack.codeplex.com/